# loading scripts when pjax do its job

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, pjax, script-tag

i have project in MVC CodeIgniter framework and i have for each view its javascripts, and it is on end of that view.

Now when pjax load that page, it should load script, but it doesnt.
Script tag is there, but its not loaded, need somehow to load it on pjax ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('change', '#grad, #adresa', function() {
            adresa = getAddress();
            marker.codeAddress(adresa);
        });
        $('#form').validator({message : ''});
        .
        .
        . // more functions


    } );
</script>
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you make alert alert after  $('body').on('change', '#grad, #adresa', function() {

Comment: is it working ? Make sure action is fired ?

Comment: alert works, but validator make error, becouse i load validator just on that page, and it isn't loaded, i mean before this script tag i load `<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/form/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>` and it isn't loaded :( and google cant load map when pjax load page

Comment: Now i have bug, whan i use function like `map.init`, so `var map = { init: function() {.....} }`, javascipt cant load that function on load, why is that happening ?

Comment: man you should also load the google map api again in your pjax loading page .
As google map will initialized again in your pjax file ...

Comment: google map api is loaded, but problem is that when pjax load data, and load it at #main_content and fragment is #main_content, so it will load data from div #main_content to current div #main_content, it loads all div, and text, and there is script tag in that div, but pjax can't load script tag to current div #main_content, can't understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but for others finding this through Google:

Scripts loaded in a PJAX request shouldn't be in a `.ready` wrapper since the document will not trigger the loaded event. The main document stays in place, only a fragment is replaced.

This means that you should init plug-ins and stuff again after the PJAX request has finished. This can get tricky sometimes.

`pjax:success` would be a great event to listen for to do this.